# Opening a new window using MVC 

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Basically I want a button that opens a page in a new window containing my `http://fake.com/Report/PageFixes...` page.  Currently I have a button in a form but if there is a better way to do it then I'm up for that too.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("PageFixes", "Report", new { id = 9 }, FormMethod.Get, new { onSubmit="window.open()" })) %>
<% { %>
    <%= Html.CSButton(new ButtonViewData() { Text = "Submit" })%>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to have a `form`.  Just add the following HTML to your view:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('<%= Url.Action("PageFixes", "Report", new { id = "9" } ) %>', '_blank'); return false;">submit</button>
```

I wasn't sure how you were getting the `9` for the `ID` but I assume it is from your model so you could replace the `"9"` with `Model.ID` or something.

The key is generating the url with `Url.Action` and then just using the basic javascript function `window.open` to open the url in a new browser window.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is what worked for me. <a href="" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("BlackBerrySummarySMACExport", new { departmentId = @ViewBag.DeptId })', '_blank', 'menubar=no'); return false;">Enterprise Blackberry Summary SMAC Report</a>

Answer (score 3):

How about just some javascript on a button like so

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://fake.com/Report/PageFixes/9')">submit</button>
```

Or if you would prefer to build the URL dynamically

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://"+Request.Url.Authority+Request.ApplicationPath %>Report/PageFixes/9')">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still do it the old-fashioned way with an onclick JavaScript function.  Here's how I did it, where I needed to pass the ID from the Model to my new URL, which was to another View that was in a folder on the same directory branch in my project:

```
<input type="button" id="@Model.Id" data-id="@Model.Id" onclick="openUrl(this)" data-myurl="/OtherBranch/Detail?id=@Model.Id" />

function openUrl(e) {
    var id = e.id;
    var obj = $("[id='"+id+"']");
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var newBranch = obj.attr('data-myurl');
    var newUrl = currentUrl.split('/FirstBranch')[0] + newBranch;
    window.open(newUrl, "", "height=600,width=400,addressbar=no,menubar=no"); // pop-up window -- should probably ensure no master page is used
    //window.location.href = newUrl; // <-- total redirect option
}
```